# Ofstream binary не работает

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

Есть код:

```
ofstream file;

file.open(path, ios::out | ios::binary);

char c = '2';

file.write(&c, sizeof(c));
file.close();
```

Открываю файл, в нем:

```
2
```

Что не так?

Comment: Надмозговый вопрос, а что, ожидалось что будет что-то другое?

Comment: Бинарный файл конечно

Comment: Файл-то бинарный. Но символ-то в него записывается текстовый.

Comment: А что такое, по-вашему, бинарный файл?

Comment: А как символ должен тогда выглядеть?

Comment: `А что такое, по-вашему, бинарный файл?`, ну в смысле двоичный

Comment: Так и должен, если просматривать его как текст.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Абстрагируясь от отличия текстовых и бинарных файлов, разница между `ios::binary` и его отсутствием такова: в текстовом режиме рантайм C++ осуществляет трансляцию символов перевода строки. То есть, символ `\n` в строке превращается в системно-зависимую строку. Например, для Windows это может быть `\r\n`. И т. д. ([Тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) большой список.) В бинарном режиме этого не происходит.

Вот и вся разница. Ничего другого при указании `ios::binary` рантайм не делает.

---

Для справки, разница между текстовыми и «бинарными» файлами такова. У текстового файла есть (системно-зависимый) формат. Он разделён на *строки*, оканчивающиеся системно-зависимым символом/ами окончания строки (`\n` в юниксе, `\r\n` в Windows и т. д.).

Двоичный же файл никакого заданного формата не имеет. Что вы туда положите, то там и будет лежать, никаких требований нет. Положите строку — будет строка.

---

Когда говорят «положите данные в бинарном виде» (в противоположность «текстовому» виду), обычно имеется в виду следующее. Числа в нетекстовом формате проще всего класть в файл «как есть»: байты, составляющие число, записать в файл, не переводя в строковое представление. Но в принципе, если формата никакого нет, вы можете класть числа в любом, удобном вам виде. Главное, чтобы они потом оттуда считались.

Comment: Ну хорошо, но ведь когда открываю любой другой бинарник, там полная абраказябра.

Comment: Потому-что там и записана полная "абраказябра". В практически любом бинарном файле можно найти цифры, буквы и даже целые строки.

Comment: @egordorichev: Почитайте дополнение в ответе.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: @egordorichev: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @egordorichev Только что мне удалось найти цифру 2 в бинарнике /bin/bash

Comment: Вряд ли она означает 2 =))

Comment: @egordorichev В вашем бинарном файле она тоже не означает 2... а скорее число 50.

Comment: @egordorichev: Дополнил ещё.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @egordorichev: Пожалуйста!