# BLOB - поле и mp3

Tags: c#, mysql

Задача: как сконвертировать выбранный mp3 файл в бинарный код и записать его в BLOB поле MySQL базы данных ? Желательно с примером. Спасибо большое !

P.S так же интересует то, как из этого поля потом отчитать файл.

re P.S да. хранить путь в бд это правильнее. но это задание, которое надо сделать !

Comment: а не проще хранить в базе только пути к файлам?

Comment: http://www.kv.by/content/324016-rabota-s-blob-polyami-mysql-c А оно точно надо? База же разрастется ужасно, почему не хотите хранить путь до mp3?

Comment: Ребята, задание такое. Именно хранить в БД.

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке, которую дал выше. Я так взглядом пробежался - вроде все это там есть.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский посмотрел, скорее всего не смогу разобраться =(

Comment: @АлексейСаровский конвертацию сделал, записываю бинарный код в txt файл (для проверки делаю пока что). А вот как от туда достать и переконвертировать из бинарного в mp3 не имею понятия =(

Comment: @kxxko: А не надо конвертировать, mp3 и есть бинарный формат уже

Comment: @VladD тогда как мне его открыть ?

Comment: Ну вообще если разобраться, то в наших компьютерах на двоичной логике все есть бинарная информация. И если открыть файл для чтения в бинарном формате - пожалуйста все уже сделано.

Comment: @kxxko BinaryReader возможно здесь поможет

Comment: @АлексейСаровский при помощи BinaryWriter создал из mp3 бинарный файл, записал его в .txt формате (потом уже как буду знать как все делать, записывать буду уже в BLOB поле).

Comment: @VladD если бы Вы не отказали бы мне в чате и помогли открыть файл mp3, был бы Вам примного благодарен !

Comment: @kxxko: Я сейчас немного занят, но ничего сложного быть не должно. Вы просто читаете все байты из файла. ([Вот немного](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419158/10105) по поводу отличия бинарных данных от текстовых).

Comment: StackOverflow - не сайт предоставляющий услуги по решению домашних заданий.

Answer (score 3):

Так как я против превращения stackoverflow в бесплатный аналог фриланс-сайтов, вот вам в качестве первого варианта ответа ссылка на одно из "правильных" мест для решения домашних/лабораторных/курсовых/дипломных работ, если не хочется включать голову и пытаться сделать самому: https://www.fl.ru/

Второй вариант (тоже без готового кода) - понять, что все данные так или иначе существуют в бинарном виде, а BLOB - ни что иное как массив байтов, т.е. byte[]. 
Не скажу точно, но уверен, что в mysql blob-поля по части "записи" и "чтения" ничем не отличаются от любых примитивных типов данных, поэтому работа с бд не должна вызвать проблем.

Чтение файлов в таком виде (т.е. чтобы результат чтения был byte[]) в c# можно, например, осуществить вот так:

```
var fileAsBytesArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

, а запись (вы не поверите!):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, fileAsBytesArray);
```

Переводить бинарные данные в текстовый формат не нужно. Вы читаете его как массив байтов, сохраняете как массив байтов в БД, потом читаете оттуда так же как массив байтов и именно их записываете обратно в файл. 
Когда вы читаете программно файл как текст, вы обычно предполагаете, что там осмысленные текстовые данные, здесь же вы ничего не предполагаете и не хотите предполагать - вам вообще пофиг mp3 это или jpg, или еще что-то. Все, что вы делаете, это читаете по байтам "как есть", сохраняете в бд, а потом читаете из нее и сохраняете файл на диск в первозданном виде.

Вот и все. Извиняюсь, если чересчур грубо.

Comment: а при чем тут "не включать голову и не думать" ?
я никого тут не просил сделать мне "домашку, лабу и т.д"
и на свои вопросы я уже получил ответы в комментариях.

Comment: в таком случае я вас наверное неправильно понял и приношу свои извинения

Comment: да ничего страшного ) все равно спасибо всем за помощь !